# VB 2010 Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'

Tags: vb.net

i wanted to make the data appear in the text box but i recived this error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox" please help

```
  txtVendorFAX = daPo.Tables("vendor").Rows(i).Item(3)
```

Comment: It's called basics... Everyone has to begin I know, but instead of posting, do some research next time : http://bit.ly/1bMq5q6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only assign a string to the `.Text` property of a `Textbox`.

**The answers given so far do not compile with Option Strict On**.

You should use:

```
txtVendorFAX.Text = daPo.Tables("vendor").Rows(i).Item(3).ToString
```

You should also make sure you have Option Strict Turned On: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/option-strict-and-option-explicit-in-vbnet-2005.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
txtVendorFAX.Text = daPo.Tables("vendor").Rows(i).Item(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
txtVendorFAX.Text = daPo.Tables("vendor").Rows(i).Item(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

txtVendorFAX.Text = Convert.ToString(daPo.Tables("vendor").Rows(i).Item(3))

Comment: No one has written Convert.ToString(). You have written .ToString which does not have closing brackets. Also by writing Convert.Tostring is more prefarable than .ToString at the end, because if incase the the value comes as null, then at times it gives error. But Convert.Tostring() will give string.empty value.

Comment: The above comment was for Mr. Matt Wilko as he gave a negative mark to my comment even after justifting my own comment.

Answer (score 0):

use `.Text` property of the textbox by using following code

```
txtVendorFAX.Text = daPo.Tables("vendor").Rows(i).Item(3)
```

a textbox is a `Textbox`, not a string. This is why you are getting the error 
`Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`